# Unable to successful detect click or change events on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, event-handling

Problem: Unable to successful detect click or change events on a checkbox.

Intent: The overall intent is to detect a change or click on a checkbox and then use jquery’s show and hide methods to display / hide elements.

My approaches so far include the following:

Method 1: Onclick Handler

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1"><center>
    <label><p>Recurring</p>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRecur()"></input></label></center>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function toggleRecur(){
console.log("something clicked"); }
```

Method 2: jquery EventListener
HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1"><center>
     <label><p>Recurring</p>
     <input type="checkbox" id="task_recur" ></input></label></center>
  </div>
```

Javascript/jquery

```
$(document).on("checked","#task_recur",function(){         
        alert("something checked");
});
```

Method 3: jquery Listener 2

```
$('input[id=task_recur]').change(function(){

if($(this).is(':checked'))
    alert("czech it");

});
```

Unfortunately, none of the above worked, whether inside or out of the document load.  I'm currently running under chrome.  Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: You should try the `onchange` event instead of `onclick` or with Jquery `$('#task_recur').change(function() { alert('clicked'); });`

Comment: This on works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/p4sv06sj/ use document.ready

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gefknLbp/1/ - works

Comment: I generally used the third method. And it should work. Check in your html that have you used the id with which you are selecting the elelment.

Answer (score 1):

**First Option**

```js
function toggleRecur(){
alert("something clicked"); }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1"><center>
    <label><p>Recurring</p>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleRecur()"></input></label></center>
</div>
```

**2nd option**

```js
document.getElementById('task_recur').onclick = function() {         
        alert("something checked");
   }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1"><center>
    <label><p>Recurring</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="task_recur" /></label></center>
</div>
```

Comment: some people just use the downvote button for no reason

Comment: @LuthandoLoot I've tried both approaches and neither seems to work for me.  Let me be more specific.  Option #1 works, but only on page refresh, not on click., which indicates that there must be something elsewhere in the html or javascript that is interfering with something.  I'll continue to experiment.  +1 for including the snippets above.

Answer (score 0):

I can see bug in only,

```
$(document).on("change", "#task_recur", function () { // event should be change not checked
    alert("delegated event");
});
```

Also,

`if($(this).is(':checked'))` can be replaced with simply `if(this.checked) {}`

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/eL3tdjc1/)</kbd>

Comment: @kovogel some people do it intentionaly to check their downvoting power

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir Thanks for the input.  What's strange is that I literally copied and pasted the code, but didn't work.  I did observe upon inspection through chrome extension, that some HTML is being generated around my element for some reason.  That's the problem with using templates. Not sure if this is a red herring, but the fact that none of the proven solutions seem to be working for me makes me believe that something on the tangent is afoot.  Thanks again.

Comment: @dellaboemia can you provide compete code...will check if I can help you

Comment: @dellaboemia solution should infact wok even when template is doing its job. As we are delegating an event and also our selector is id selector . strange...

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('task_recur').onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert("Checked);
    }
};
```

With jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", "#task_recur", function(){         
    alert("something checked");
});


$('#task_recur').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        alert("czech it");
});
```

Comment: tried both approaches, but no luck.  As I mention below, I think I may have some other issue that is interfering with things.  I will continue to work the problem and advise should I discover something interesting.